# I can not find indices in kibana web client

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-7

Today I used Logstash input a dataset succesfully, but I can not find it in Kibana Web-end, could you help me? (PS:My English is not very well expressed, please don't mind)

[image: Kibana web screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you are not sending your data to elasticsearch.   An you share the configuration of the Elasticsearch output ?

Comment: @Gillespie59  I promise it send successfully, the data was print in stdout~

Comment: check it on Index Patterns of Kibana section

Comment: Can you share your Logstash configuration? If there was data in Elaticsearch it would show on that page.